# Tensorflow unnecessary imports?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am working through a tutorial on neural style transfer with tensorflow and am trying to understand the basic canonical imports. First, we are presented with:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing import image as kp_image
from tensorflow.python.keras import models 
from tensorflow.python.keras import losses
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

My confusion here is why exactly we need to call python and keras inside of the tensorflow imports. My thoughts are that since python and keras are both dependencies for tensorflow this may be the reason. However isn't python a dependency for all packages?

Why can we not just call:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import images as kp_image
```

Any help as well as an intuitive explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It may be called somewhere in your code. what is imported is related to preprocessing stuff. To make an analogy, suppose you've imported sqrt from math library.

Comment: That makes sense for the Keras import, but would Python be being called directly for something?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot see the images in DS. Please change the image to code snippet to see what you've done.

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect this change.

Comment: As you may have noticed, you've not imported Python. In TensorFlow, there are different modules and files. What you have done here is that you've imported layers module to use it later to construct layers of your network. Please consider that you are just importing different modules from the TensorFlow library which each reside in different directories.

Comment: On the other hand, you've not imported Keras too. Keras itself is a different open-source high-level library. Inside tensorflow, there is support for fast implementation of networks which is inspired by the Keras project and contains things which are available in Keras library. What you've done in your code is irrelevant to Keras library.